# Showing $K_1= H+\sqrt{H^2-K}$ and $k_2=H-\sqrt{H^2-K}$

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to show the principle curvatures $k_1$ and $k_2$ are given by are given by $K_1= H+\sqrt{H^2-K}$ and $k_2=H-\sqrt{H^2-K}$

This is what I have so far:

The Gaussian curvature $K$ and mean curvature $H$ are related to $k_1$ and $k_2$ by $$K=k_1k_2$$ and $$H=\frac{1}{2}(k_1=k_2)$$

I am told this can be written as the quadratic equation $$K_n^2-2Hk_n+K=0$$

Where $k_n$ represents the extreme values of the curvature.

Solving this we find the expressions for $k_1$ and $k_2$.

> My question is, where does the quadratic equation $K_n^2+2Hk_n+K=0$
>   come from?

Comment: Do you maybe mean $k_{n}^{2}-2Hk_{n}+K=0$?

Comment: @sanichodgeheg changed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that the quadratic equation is true by simply substituting in the given expressions for $H$ and $K$, but if you want some motivation, here's how you might arrive at it.

Say we want to solve for $k_n$. From the definition of the mean curvature we get $$ k_n = 2H - k_m$$ where $m=2$ if $n=1$ and vice versa. Now substitute $k_m = K/k_n$ (from the definition of $K$) and we get

$$k_n = 2H - K/k_n.$$
Multiplying through by $k_n$ and moving everything to the LHS we get $$k_n^2 - 2Hk_n + K = 0.$$